# How to drop specific rows in multiindex dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I'd like to drop rows relating to 'Technology' sector where alpha vector values are negative. The index is composed of two sections, level 0 'date' and level 1 'asset'.

```
                             alpha_vector   sector
date    asset       
2019-06-28 00:00:00+00:00   A     1.218573  Healthcare
                            AA    1.247386  Basic Materials
                            AAL   1.842296  Industrials
                            AAP   -0.713696 Consumer Cyclical
                            AAPL  3.370962  Technology
                            AAXN  -1.892290 Industrials
                            ABB   1.525332  Industrials
                            ABBV  4.647228  Healthcare
                            ABC   1.421925  Healthcare
                            ABMD  3.130564  Healthcare
                            ABT   -6.842299 Healthcare
                            ACAD  -2.015420 Healthcare
                            ACC   0.448264  Real Estate
                            ACGL  -1.179464 Financial Services
                            ACIA  2.839611  Technology

... ... ... ...
2020-06-26 00:00:00+00:00   WRK   5.098169  Consumer Cyclical
                            WSM   -8.620308 Consumer Cyclical
                            WSO   -9.874210 Industrials
                            WST   -10.74130 Healthcare
                            WU    1.267384  Financial Services
                            WWD   3.379096  Industrials
                            WWE   -0.766277 Consumer Cyclical
```

`226296 rows × 2 columns`

I've tried this:

```
for date in df.index.levels[0]:
    for ticker in  df.index.levels[1]:
        if (df.loc[(date,ticker),'sector'] == 'Technology') and (df.loc[(date,ticker),'alpha_vector'] < 0):
            df.drop((date,ticker),inplace =True)
```

however it takes too long to execute.

Comment: Show your sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need selections by conditions:

```
drop_rows_condition = (df.sector == 'Technology') & (df.alpha_vector < 0)
df = df[ ~drop_rows_condition ]
```